# Read XML child node attributes using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-attribute

I have one XML column (Criteria) in table (Qualifications) which contains different XML:

```
<training ID="173"><badge ID="10027" /><badge ID="10028" /></training>
<book Category="Hobbies And Interests" PropertyName="C#" CategoryID="44" />
<sport Category="Hobbies And Interests" PropertyName="Cricket" CategoryID="46" />
<education ID="450" School="Jai ambe vidyalaya"></education>
```

I want to read the "badge" node "ID" attributes for all nodes under the "training" node.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IDs of `badge` elements inside `training` only

```
select t.c.value('.', 'int') ID
from Qualifications q
    cross apply q.Criteria.nodes('//training[badge]/badge[@ID]/@ID') t(c)
```

IDs of `badge` elements anywhere (not only inside `training`)

```
select t.c.value('.', 'int') ID
from Qualifications q
    cross apply q.Criteria.nodes('//badge[@ID]/@ID') t(c)
```

If `Criteria` column is `nvarchar` type, you can cast to `xml` as:

```
select t.c.value('.', 'int') ID
from Qualifications q
    cross apply (select convert(xml, q.Criteria) xmlCriteria) a
    cross apply a.xmlCriteria.nodes('//training[badge]/badge[@ID]/@ID') t(c)
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this sample, it should help (just replace @xml with your table/column name)

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml ='
<training ID="173">
    <badge ID="10027" />
    <badge ID="10028" />
</training>
<book Category="Hobbies And Interests" PropertyName="C#" CategoryID="44" />
<sport Category="Hobbies And Interests" PropertyName="Cricket" CategoryID="46" />
<education ID="450" School="Jai ambe vidyalaya"></education>'

SELECT data.col.value('(@ID)[1]', 'int')
FROM @xml.nodes('(/training/badge)') AS data(col)
```

Output:

```
10027
10028
```